# Two separate AuthN methods for one Grails app

Tags: spring, api, authentication, grails, spring-security

I have a Grails application running that uses an external CAS login method and uses a local user list for authorization.  I am using the spring-security and spring-security-cas plugins and everything is working great.

I am now implementing a RESTful API under a sub-domain of the application (/api) and want to provide security for that as well.  I have read that setting up HTTP basic AuthN is easy with Grails, but have found nothing on using 2 security paradigms within one application.  Aside from separating the API to a separate application, is there a way to implement a separate authentication method for just the /api sub-domain on my application?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no simple way to accomplish this, so I ended up using IP-based access control for the API (since only a few people will be using it).  I did this by editing the web.xml file in my grails app and adding a Remote Address Filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>**IP ADDRESSES HERE**</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also had to disable CAS authentication for the api, which I accomplished by adding permissions in the interceptUrlMap in Config.groovy:

```
'/api/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
```